# How to solve java.io.InvalidClassException : local class incompatible with Scala Spark with ALS

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-submit

I am trying to train an ALS algorithm on Spark-Submit, saving the model on HDFS and its predictions on Cassandra with Cassandra connector.

The train occurs without any problem but I have either this error

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.math.Ordering$$anonfun$by$1; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3410834592477398573, local class serialVersionUID = 0
```

or this one :

```
 java.io.InvalidClassException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.ReadConf; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3166370729900710116, local class serialVersionUID = -7280317430045994784
```

It seems that I have some incompatible library. I tried to overcome this problem with various change on the build.sbt (following)

```
val sparkVersion = "2.2.1"
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org","aopalliance", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "inject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "codahale", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "yammer", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("META-INF", ps @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "overview.html" => MergeStrategy.last  // Added this for 2.1.0 I think
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}


lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Perso_ALS",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
    resolvers += "Apache Maven Central Repository" at "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/",
    libraryDependencies += "com.github.fommil.netlib" % "all" % "1.1.2" pomOnly(),
    libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.6",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion exclude("org.xerial.snappy", "snappy-java"),
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % sparkVersion,
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib-local" % sparkVersion,    
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion, 
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.10.0",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.10.0",  
    libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3",
    libraryDependencies += "org.xerial.snappy" % "snappy-java" % "1.1.7.1",
    libraryDependencies += "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.0.43.Final",
    libraryDependencies += "commons-net" % "commons-net" % "2.2",
    libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "11.0.2",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" %  "2.11.4"
  )
```

I also tried to add lines `dependenciesOverride` without any success

Does anyone have ever recountered this kind of problem, how to solve it ? 
I am using Spark 2.2.1 and Scala 2.11 (to be compatible with Cassandra connector) is there something to change about this ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the same version of Spark on **all** nodes of your cluster?

Comment: Yes I have, I have done the installation of the same Spark version

Comment: The class it's complaining about is a Scala-provided one. It seems that you upgraded/downgraded scala (directly or through a difference dependency). It could be that you have not deployed your uber jar on all servers or you are running the driver with code on a modified classpath. Remember that you also shouldn't include dependencies that are already provided by the Spark runtime

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I understand well I should verify if I have the right Scala on the cluster and the corresponding scala library during the sbt assembly ?

Comment: Not just that... Even more importantly, you need to check which version of scala dependencies you're packaging in your spark application archive

Comment: I verified the scala version of the cluster which is 2.11.6, I changed it in the build.sbt but I already have an error `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy`

Comment: Thanks, it changed the error !